Dynamic blog - Gantry 5 - Joomla
I am a bit stuck at the moment on how to structure my blog. I am trying to have a left side menu which will show the different categories of articles and the right block should show all the article from the category you click on. Then click on the article you want to read and it will show up full.
Not sure how to link all of it together. I am using Gantry 5 on Joomla 5 to build my website. I can get the menu block in the layout and the article block too. The issue is that it will only show the articles the gantry particles is linked to. The particle isnt linked to the menu module.
Gantry layout:

Below is the template I would to reproduce.

My website blog.
At the moment I have only one category and 2 articles showing up for that category. Read more button doesnt even work. The menu is the two articles but I will change it to categories once I have more content.
I will appreciate some help on how to do that.
Thank you
